# Timeit decorator for Random Forest fitting

Tags: python, decorator, execution-time

I am trying to use below decorator to measure the time that it takes to fit my Random Forest model:

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time
def timeit(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time()
        print 'Elapsed time: {}'.format(end-start)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

However when I run below code I cannot see the elapsed time:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(**_rf_params)
timeit(rf.fit)(train_features, train_labels)
```

How can I use this decorator to see how long the fitting took?
(running on Python 2.7)

Comment: Tested with a mock `rf.fit` and it worked just fine. What *can* you see when running this? Does it return the correct result? Does it actually run `fit`?

Comment: @tituszban: I was running this in PyCharm in Debug mode and it did not display the elapsed time. However, I have executed the code in Run mode now and it produces the desired result. Any idea why this doesn't work in Debug mode?

Comment: I can't see anything that would break in Debug mode. Just double checking that you're looking at the right output: can you see any other print statements? Also, just FWI, Python 2 is no longer supported. Consider upgrading to 3